# in_array not giving desired output - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below PHP code which does the following:

- Uploads 2 csv files
- Stores elements of header (1st row) of csv into an array
- Stores elements of second column of csv into an array
- Checks if array 2 exists in array 1 (and it should).

However, the if & in_array block at the end always says that they do not match. Even though they do.

I am a beginner in PHP. Could someone please point what am I doing wrong?

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $UploadFileToServerRenamed);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mappingfile']['tmp_name'], $UploadMappingFileToServerRenamed);

$fpmainfile = fopen($UploadFileToServerRenamed, "r");
$header = fgetcsv($fpmainfile, 4096, ';', '"');

fclose($fpmainfile);

Print_r ($header);

 $csv = array();

 if(($handle = fopen($UploadMappingFileToServerRenamed, "r")) !== FALSE)
 {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $csv[] = $data;

    }
 }

 fclose($handle);

 $fp = file($UploadMappingFileToServerRenamed, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
 echo "<br>";
 $fpcount = count($fp);
  echo "<br>";


 $column = 1;
 $columnarray = array();

 for ($row = 1; $row < $fpcount; $row++) 
 {  
    $datapoint = $csv[$row][$column];
    $columnarraypush = array_push($columnarray, $datapoint);
    $columnarraypush = $columnarray;
}


echo "No of columns";
echo "<br>";
echo $fpcount;
echo "<br>";
echo "column starts here";
echo "<br>";
 print_r($columnarraypush);  echo "<br>";



   $result=array_intersect($columnarraypush, $header);
print_r($result); echo "<br>"; 

 if(in_array($columnarraypush, $header))
 {
     echo "hurray"; echo "<br>";
 }
 else
 {
     echo "boo"; echo "<br>";
 }
```

I added array intersect but seem to get no hits:
Below is the echo:

> Array ( [0] => Incident Number,Month,Description,Status,Status
>   Reason,Submit Date,SUBMITTER GROUP,REPORTED DATE,Location
>   Compnay,Location Site,Location Site Group,Business Unit,Tag
>   Number,Assigned Support Company,Assigned Support
>   Organization,ASSIGNEE,Assigned Group,ASSIGNED GROUP
>   SHIFT,Impact,Urgency,Priority,Priority Weight,SERVICE TYPE,Ticket
>   Type,Last Resolved Date,Last Resolved By,Resolution Method,PROD CAT
>   TIER 1,PROD CAT TIER 2,PROD CAT TIER 3,Res Cat Tier 1,Res Cat Tier
>   2,Res Cat Tier 3,Op Category Tier 1,Op Category Tier 2,Op Category
>   Tier 3,Closure Prod Cat Tier 1,Closure Prod Cat Tier 2,Closure Prod
>   Cat Tier 3,Closure Product Name,Closure Prod Model Ver,CLOSED DATE,OP
>   CAT,OP CAT1,OP CAT2,RES CODE,RES CODE 1,RES CODE
>   2,Reconfiguration,Delivery model,Improvement
>   Model,Description,Resolution Method,REGION OF SUPPORT,HPD
>   REGION,Country,Company,Site,Elapsed Seconds,Delayed Seconds,Sev 1 or 2
>   SLA Hours,Submit Date2,Day,Submit Month,Country,Vol,SLTime,HD
>   Resolved,HD Resolved 15Minutes,HD Resolved 30Minutes,HD Resolved
>   60Minutes,SLA,SLA HD Resolved,Aging,Aging Group )
>
> No of columns 16 column starts here Array ( [0] => Incident Number [1]
>   => Description [2] => Status [3] => Assigned Group [4] => Priority [5] => Business Unit [6] => Ticket Type [7] => Op Category Tier 1 [8] => Op Category Tier 2 [9] => REGION OF SUPPORT [10] => Country [11] =>
>   Reconfiguration [12] => Submit Date [13] => [14] => Elapsed Seconds )
>   Array Diff starts here 
>   Array ( )
>    boo

Comment: in_array is used to check if a value exists inside an array or not. It is not used to check if two arrays are equal

Comment: Use array_diff or array_intersect depending on what output you want

Comment: Could you show us the the two things are the same? Maybe add to your question the output of the two variables in the the `in_array`?

Comment: Thanks. I added array_intersect but got no matches. I also added my echoes into the question

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. The first array is one big string under one index. The second one is different strings under different indices. How can I save the first one with multiple indeces?